Lost my order by clause working with EFCore
Good evening.
I encountered an issue with a query using EFCore (Pomelo EF 8, .NET 8).
The code that invokes the query is as follows:
List<SelectListItem> retmodel = await dbContext.Certifications
    .Where(c => brevettiChePuoEmettere.Contains(c.Id) && c.Attivo == 1)
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.Livello).ThenBy(c => c.Descrizione)
    .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Id.ToString(), Text = c.Descrizione, Selected = c.Id == selected })
    .Distinct()
    .ToListAsync();

The output query is:
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(`t`.`Id` AS char) AS `Value`, `t`.`Descrizione` AS `Text`, `t`.`Id` = @__selected_1 AS `Selected`
FROM `t_certifications` AS `t`
WHERE `t`.`Id` IN (2, .........) AND (`t`.`Attivo` = 1)

Where did my order by clause go?
I also tried changing the ordering in the fluent API, but nothing changed.
Thanks to anyone who can offer a suggestion.

Could you share the table definitions? This does seem like something was lost in translation.

That's what happens when having Distinct after sorting.

Livello is not part of result. Do you still need ordering by this field?

I've solved in a different way:
var cert = await dbContext.Certifications
.Where(c => brevettiChePuoEmettere.Contains(c.Id) && c.Attivo == 1)
.OrderBy(c => c.Livello).ThenBy(c => c.Descrizione)
.ToListAsync();
List retmodel = cert
.Distinct()
.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Id.ToString(), Text = c.Descrizione, Selected = c.Id == selected })
.ToList();
And the result is what I expected

Of course  Svyatoslav Danyliv.
Divers Certifications are ordered by categories (livello) then by Description. It isn't a part of resultset but is important for a correct ordering

I found these EF Core GitHub issues:

Missing ORDER BY
OrderBy is ignored when used with Distinct and then Concatenated #28399

From these I understand that the .OrderBy() call is "discarded" (i.e. it does not get translated into SQL code) in such scenarios because SQL Server in some cases does not allow ORDER BY to be present, and in other cases would ignore it if present.
Unfortunately the discard inside EF Core happens silently. Part of the discussions is about if EF should instead print a Warning or throw an Exception when .OrderBy() is followed by .Distinct().
The fix should be easy in most cases: do .Distinct() first, then .OrderBy().
